# Kann man Antonyme der Form „Richtigkeit“ und „Unrichtigkeit“ beim Listen abkürzen

Tags: abbreviation

Dass man Worte, die eine gemeinsame Wurzel haben und die sich nur durch ein unterschiedliches Präfix voneinander unterscheiden, beim Listen anhand eines Bindestrichs abkürzen kann (soll?) ist wohlbekannt.

Kann man etwas Ähnliches für etwa Antonyme der form

> `X` und `Präfix`+`X`

beim Listen abkürzen?

Z. B. wäre

> Richtigkeit und Un-

verständlich?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Grundsätzlich ist dies nicht empfehlenswert. Es ist zwar üblich im deutschen Raum (Umgangssprache) etwas wie

> Un-/Richtigkeit oder
>   (Un-) Richtigkeit

zu schreiben, jedoch ist die Form in Listen sehr ungebräuchlich und nicht zu empfehlen.

Ähnlich verhält es sich auch mit Suffixen für Antonyme, so ist z.B.

> Verständnis/-losigkeit

im Umgangsstil nicht ungebräuchlich, allerdings nicht in der Listenform.

Sowohl bei Präfixen als auch Suffixen sollte man also für Antonyme auf eine solche Listenform verzichten.

*Update:* Sollte man nur den generellen Suffix abkapseln wollen, so kann man das natürlich wie bei jedem anderen deutschen Wort auch ausführen. Also z.B. hier nur das entfallende "-keit":

> Richtig- und Unrichtigkeit

Comment: Richtig- und Unrichtigkeit ginge auch.

Comment: @tofro Absolut richtig, ich ergänze das.